# libGDX camera.unproject() returns NaN

Tags: java, android, camera, libgdx

I have a basic LibGDX project where I want to get the touch position but Android devices give it's screen coordinates rather than the virtual game coordinates so I am using camera.unproject() to get to get the right coordinates. What I get in result is NaN (not a number) for the x,y values I get back. Why could this be happening?

Comment: There are many possible causes. Consider including the actual code.

Comment: Might be a camera viewport with 0 size, or maybe near == far values of a perspective camera.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone has similar problem. Adding

```
    @Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
    gamePort.update(width, height);
}
```

where gamePort is instance of Viewport should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the camera/viewport was set incorrectly. A fresh set-up solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to perform `camera.update` before `camera.unproject` to get valid world coordinates. I'm using `camera.unproject` during the camera setup and realized that it is not enough to call the update method just at the end of the setup.